# Remove Downloadable Product required field

Tags: php, magento

I\’m facing the same problem. I create a downloadable product with upload file....and then on frontend this is a mandatory field and the user can not send it directly to the basket. I have no clou where this mandatory field comes from and how to disable it.

Comment: Explain your question in such a way atleast i can get /understand

Comment: **I have no clou where this mandatory field comes from and how to disable it** We also have no clue... Give us something to look at, and explain it...